# Getting a single html list element back to my spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a kind of unique problem - nothing that I could find an answer or example on.

I have a jsp page which shows an individual product, the user has an option to select a size and then add it to their cart, now all of my database work is already done and working - I am trying to find a way to get what size the user selected, and then forward that back to my controller which will grab the correct kind of product (in the size the user selected).

Here is my code from my jsp

```
<ul class="options list-unstyled">
    <h4 class="m_9">Select a Size</h4>
    <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">XL</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the submit button that would add to the cart.

```
<form:form />
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" title="">
</form:form>
```

I am thinking I should surround the ul tag in a the form tags and the surround each li in a form:input or maybe form:hidden tag, is that possible?

I would like to avoid jquery/javascript and work with spring java/jsp primarily - just because I am strapped for time and the learning curve for accomplishing what I need may be too high so page refreshing isnt an issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use JavaScript and you don't mind refreshing, then you can have your sizes as URL parameters, and have the controller refresh the current page with the appropriate product.

```
<ul class="options list-unstyled">
    <h4 class="m_9">Select a Size</h4>
    <li><a href="?size=s">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="?size=m">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="?size=l">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="?size=xl">XL</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", params = "size", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProduct(@RequestParam String size, Model model){
    if ("s".equals(size)) {
        // add small product to model
    } else if ("m".equals(size)) {
        // add medium product to model
    }
    ....
    return "...";
}
```

A better approach is to have the sizes inside a `select` tag in the form. The controller will get the size when the form is submitted, and insert the appropriate product accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the response, that will work! I had thought about the select tag, but I would rather it wasnt a drop down menu - its currently setup [S M L XL] user clicks one of those and then click add to cart button - in my case should I surround the list in the form tag? I am loosing where the jsp has a reference to my "/product" RequestMapping. Thank you